como puedo indexar una parte del articulo del html, en el mismo codigo, sin utilizar archivos extras
como puedo indexar una parte del articulo del html, en el mismo codigo, sin utilizar archivos extras, ya que necesito un menu para navegar en la pagina y sus secciones
ocupe el siguiente codigo:
> 
<button>
  <img src="C:\Users\alega\Desktop\Aplicaciones\Pagina\imagenes\sonriente.jpg"
    width="300" height="300"><br>HABILIDADES</a>
</button>
<a href="C:\Users\alega\Desktop\Aplicaciones\Pagina\sub2.html" target=_black>
  <button>
    <img src="C:\Users\alega\Desktop\Aplicaciones\Pagina\imagenes\personaje.jpg"
      width="300" height="300"><br>PERSONAJE</a>
  </button>

<a href="C:\Users\alega\Desktop\Aplicaciones\Pagina\sub3.html" target=_black>
  <button>
    <img src="C:\Users\alega\Desktop\Aplicaciones\Pagina\imagenes\muerte.jpg" 
      width="300" height="300"><br>MUERTE</a>
  </button>

lo cual no era lo que buscaba, por que ocupo otros documentos para tener distintas secciones en la pagina, pero lo necesito en la misma

Siempre es bueno buscar antes
